# SQL Server : extract strings from delimiter

Tags: sql-server, substring

I'm query a column called Description and I need to extract strings from each of the "-" delimiters;

e.g.

```
Description            
---------------------------------
abc@abc.com - Invoice - A12222203
FGH@fgh.com - Credit -  C12222333
```

So ideally need to extract each segment into three separate columns;

e.g.

```
Email       | Doc Type | Ref       
------------+----------+----------
abc@abc.com | Invoice  | A12222203 
FGH@fgh.com | Credit   | C12222333
```

I have managed to extract the email address using

```
Substring(SL_Reference,0,charindex('-',SL_Reference))Email
```

Any ideas how I can split the two remaining sections into individual columns (i.e. Doc type and ref)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be hundreds of ways to do this string manipulation, here are a couple.

This uses `apply` to get the positions of each delimeter then simple string manipulation to get each part.

```
with myTable as (
    select * from (values('abc@abc.com - Invoice - A12222203'),('FGH@fgh.com - Credit - C12222333'))v(Description)
)
select
    Trim(Left(description,h1-1)) Email, 
    Trim(Substring(description,h1+1,Len(description)-h2-h1-1)) DocType,
    Trim(Right(description,h2-1)) Ref
from mytable
cross apply(values(CharIndex('-',description)))v1(h1)
cross apply(values(CharIndex('-',Reverse(description))))v2(h2)
```

This splits the string into rows then conditionally aggregates back into one row.

```
with myTable as (
    select * from (values('abc@abc.com - Invoice - A12222203'),('FGH@fgh.com - Credit -  C12222333'))v(Description)
)
select 
    max(Iif(rn=1,v,null)) Email,
    max(Iif(rn=2,v,null)) Doctype,
    max(Iif(rn=3,v,null)) Ref
from mytable
cross apply (
    select Trim(value)v,row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn
    from String_Split(Description,'-') 
)s
group by Description
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.
Please can you advise how i can incorporate this into my existing select statement, and reference column with that query?

Comment: @NiteHawk - What existing select statement? There is nothing in your question other than the sample data which I am assuming is in a table *MyTable* in the above query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. sorry I figured that out.
I used this Youtube video to help with using the with statement into my existing query https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5KGjqnMss7g to figure it out.

Last question, do you know why some strings are not splitting with the "-" delimiter?

also for some reason part of the email was split (e.g. uk.eu@XXXXX.com)

![](https://ibb.co/LtT0wCn)


Many thanks for your  help! much appreciated